# BackboneJS + Codeigniter convert API result as string

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, backbone.js

I have this Backbone App where I use `Codeigniters` Restful API. I have this feature where I fetch `Artistnames` from my MySQL db. Right now, my API gives me the result like this:

```
{"artist_name" : "Queens of the stone age"}
```

What I want to achieve is that I get the name like `/queensofthestoneage`. How can I achieve that?

My Backbone View looks like this:

```
function (App, Backbone) {
    var Artistname = App.module();

    Artistname.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: 'artistname',
        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'all', this.render)
        },
        serialize: function() {
            return this.collection ? this.collection.toJSON() : [];
        }
    });
    Artistname.ArtistnameCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: function() {
            return '/project/ci/index.php/api/artistchannel/artistname/' + this.artist_id;
        }
    });

    return Artistname;
}
```

My Codeigniter/API MySQL query looks like this:

```
public function a_artists_get()  
{ 
  $this->load->database();
  $sql = "SELECT formated_name FROM `artists` WHERE formated_name LIKE 'A%'";
  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
  $data = $query->result();

  if($data) {
     $this->response($data, 200);
  } else {
     $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artists with letter a!'), 404);
  }
}
```

Any help is welcome!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you talking about on the client or server side?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about server side, in PHP, you can use either use `str_replace()` to strip out spaces, or `preg_replace()` to strip out any whitespace with a regex. Then use `strtolower()` to convert to lower case before converting the data into JSON:

```
echo strtolower(preg_replace("/\s+/", '', "Queens of the Stone Age"));
echo strtolower(str_replace(" ", '', "Queens of the Stone Age"));
```

If you can guarantee that spaces will be all that appears in the data from MySQL (eg no carriage returns), then `str_replace()` is the way to go as it's faster. Otherwise, I would probably use the regex approach as it will remove all whitespace.

Comment: Ah ok! I updated my question, so could I include your suggestion there?

Comment: Yes. `$data` will be an associative array so you would need to put in something like `$data['artist_name'] = strtolower(preg_replace("/\s+/", '', $data['artist_name']));` after the query and before the IF statement.

Comment: Following your example, it says `Undefined index: artist_name`

Comment: That's because that key doesn't exist in the associative array. You need to use whatever the name of that field is in the database.

Comment: the field of the table is actually `formated_name`, but I get the same error-message `undefined index: formated_name`

Comment: You need to use `$query->result_array()` rather than `$query->result()` if you want to return the data as an array. If you use `$query->result()` that returns an object, so the syntax you would need to use to access it would be `$data->formated_name`